# How to filter List of Maps in Scala

Tags: scala

My list of Maps is like below

```
val myMap=  List(
    Map("name" -> "1st" , "status" -> "0"),
    Map("name" -> "2nd" , "status" -> "1"),
    Map("name" -> "3rd" , "status" -> "1")
  )
```

I am trying to `filter` the `list` based on `"status" = "1"` and get another `List of Maps` with only `name`

So the output should be

```
Map("name" -> "2nd"),
Map("name" -> "3rd")
```

I am a beginner in scala, understand that I need to apply `map,filter`. But not getting how to proceed here.

Comment: Take a look at the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) and try to implement it yourself. If you get stuck come back and edit the question with what you tried and why it didn't work, so we can provide better help than just giving you the code. - BTW, if all your maps have the same fields then it is probably better to use a **case class** to model your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing both `filter` and `map` the best solution is often to use `collect`:

```
myMap.collect{ case m if m.get("status").contains("1") => m - "status" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider combining `filter` & `map` into [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D):List%5BB%5D):

```
val myMap = List(
    Map("name" -> "1st", "status" -> "0"),
    Map("name" -> "2nd", "status" -> "1"),
    Map("name" -> "3rd", "status" -> "1"),
    Map("xx" -> "4th",   "status" -> "1"),
    Map("name" -> "5th", "yy" -> "1")
  )

myMap.collect{ case m if m.get("status").contains("1") && m.get("name").nonEmpty =>
    Map("name" -> m("name"))
}
// List(Map(name -> 2nd), Map(name -> 3rd))
```

The guard clause in `collect` ensures that only those `Map`s consisting of key-value `status->1` as well as key `name` will be included.

Comment: `m.get("name").get` is just `m("name")` but `m.filter(_._1 == "name")` is perhaps cleaner anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, `m("name")` is better, thanks.  Not sure `filter` in this case would be optimized to the equivalence of `get` (i.e. O(1)) though.

Answer (score 0):

With `filter` and `map` you can write is as follows

```
myMap
  .filter(m => m.get("status") == Some("1")) // filter maps with status 1
  .map(m => "name" -> m.get("name").get)     // use the name attribute to create a new map
```

Note that the `get` method returns an `Option` since the requested key might not exist. Therefore you need to compare with `Some("1")` and also use the `.get` on the result of `m.get("name")`. Using the `.get` method without checking that the option is not empty is not a good style, since this will fail at runtime if the map doesn't contain a `name` key.
A better approach which would omit these maps from the result could be

```
myMap
  .filter(m => m.get("status") == Some("1"))
  .flatMap(m => m.get("name").map(n => "name" -> n))
```

The map used here is from the `Option` class and will map a found name to `Some("name" -> n)` and `None` to `None`. The `flatMap` will finally unpack the `Some` and ignore the `None` elments

Comment: Instead of `someOption == Some("x")`, in recent (starting from 2.11, I think) versions of Scala, it's more efficient to write `someOption.contains("x")`, which saves at least an allocation.